# How to remove empty XML tags generated due to null input in IIB - ESQL

Tags: xml, conditional-statements, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

Working in ESQL compute nodes - IIB. I have an input path like Destination/Address/Country which is NULL ie Country tag is not available inside Destination/Address for a few inputs.
In the output XML, CountryDesc has only child 'Country'. If input field is NULL, CountryDesc should also not get created.

`SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.Parcel.Arr_Address.CountryDesc.Country = InputRoot.XMLNSC.Destination.Address.Country;`

But Output has an empty tag, `<CountryDesc/>`. How to eliminate this empty tag generation, without using an IF condition like `IF Destination.Address.Country IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(Destination.Address.Country) <> '' THEN --assign`

I was thinking about a procedure that would parse through all nodes and delete the empty child. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should be aware that the word 'null' has a specific meaning when discussing data formats. This might be helpful:

- Empty: The field exists and has a value that conforms to the field's data type. The value is zero-length. Only possible for string fields because (for example) a zero-length integer is not a valid integer.
- Null: The field exists and has a special, allowed value that signals that the value should not be processed in the normal way. In XML, this is done by including an attribute `xsi:nil="true"`
- Missing: The field is not present at all in the input

Your question about removing empty tags is a good one, and has been answered on MQSeries.net: http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=14579

I would advise caution though; I have not used or reviewed the code posted in that thread and you should unit test it thoroughly yourself.

Comment: For the particular condition, I meant NULL as in the field was not present in the input. But I would like to handle all the cases, where an empty tag is generated.
Thanks for the link. I will try out and update.

Comment: I knew what you meant, but you should not really use the word 'NULL' in that way. NULL is a value. When the entire field is missing it does not even have a value.